# Lwc checkbox unselect first checkbox when any other check box selected

Tags: javascript, checkbox, salesforce, lwc

In an salesforce lwc project i have a list of checkboxes populated with an array. The requirement is that when any other checkbox is selected it unselects the first one. I am trying this code

```
@track acc_array = [];

  get options() {
    return [
      { label: "Any option", value: "Any option" },
      { label: "Option One", value: "Option One" },
      { label: "Option Two", value: "Option Two" },
      { label: "Option Three", value: "Option Three" }
    ];
  }
handleValidity(e) {
    try {
      
      var arr = e.target.value.join(";");
      const tt = arr.split(";");
      if (tt[0] == "Any Option" && tt.length > 1) {
        tt.splice(0);
        this.acc_array = tt;
      }
      this.message = "Selected " + this.acc_array;
    } catch (e) {
      this.message = "Error " + e;
    }

<lightning-checkbox-group
    class="slds-box"
    label="Select a color"
    options={options}
    value={acc_array}
    onchange={handleValidity}
```